# Boot looping after install

Tags: boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit

Just installed PI OS LITE (64-BIT) on an SSD for my Pi 4B using the Raspberry Pi Imager (on a Windows machine).
On first boot it keeps looping as follows:

1. Rainbow splash screen
2. "mmc1: Controller never released inhibit bit(s)" in top left of screen
3. "Resizing root filesystem..."
4. "Generating SSH keys" shows for less than 5 seconds
5. "Fix PARTUUID" only shows for a fraction of a second (had to film my screen to be able to read it)
6. "Rebooting in 5 seconds..."
7. Screen goes black and we start back at 1

I tried reinstalling the OS to the SSD, but same result.

I had the 32-bit version of Pi OS Lite working earlier on the same SSD. Ran into compatibility issues, so trying to upgrade to 64-bit now.

I'm a noob when it comes to Pi's or Linux in general, so probably a mistake on my end.
Anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? If possible please explain in terms a Windows user can understand :)

Comment: step 5 may be a request for you to do something

Comment: Steps 1-6 are normal. I suspect your problem is the inability of the Pi to power your (unspecified) SSD. Why would you WANT to use a SSD for a Lite install?

Comment: What happens if you try using an sd card to boot?

Comment: I use an SSD to run Docker on which I plan to run Home Assistant and some other services. I don't really like using SD cards as boot drives because I expect a lot of random writes and that makes SD cards die quick. I'll check if I can boot from another device though thanks

Comment: How many SD Cards have you seen fail? This is a Pi urban myth. I have cards > 10 years old and Pi that have been running for > 4 years.

Comment: @Milliways you really want to start that discussion here? If a user wants to boot from an SSD for whatever reason, I say let them.

Comment: I never said don't but if you are basing your decision on a falsehood I will suggest corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Milliways](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8697/milliways) was right. It seems the Pi isn't always powerful enough to run a 2.5 inch SSD over an unpowered USB to SATA cable.

Now using a USB to SATA cable that has an external power adapter and I can boot into Pi OS with no problems.